# Stop buffering of adb shell output

Tags: adb

I observed this new behavior in `adb` v1.0.39. The command:

```
adb shell getevent -l
```

gives the output below:

[image: Observe that the last line is not complete]

Observe that the last line is incomplete. This happens on many different devices. The same command is working without buffering in `adb` v1.0.32.

How do I stop `adb shell` output buffering in `adb` v1.0.39?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `adb exec-out` instead of `adb shell` command to force the new `adb` to use the `raw` mode and avoid stdout buffering.

For more info read comments in [shell_service.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb/+/master/shell_service.cpp)

Comment: This works. Can you also tell is this android device version specific? I need a way to determine that for a given device, should i use the `adb shell` or `adb exec-out` @alex-p

Comment: just use `adb exec-out`. The `adb` client will automatically negotiate use of older `adb shell` protocol with devices which do not support `adb shell V2`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this behavior using adb 1.0.41.

Only while using tr which I use to delete "\r". In this case I use:

```
adb command ... | stdbuf -o0 tr -d $'\r'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex P. gave an excellent answer. Except that using either `exec-out` or `shell` in fact is device-specific. For example, my Galaxy Note 4 streams event data perfectly via `shell` (that is: `adb.exe shell getevent /dev/input/event2`), but buffers it and posts with large chunks when using `exec-out` (command: `adb exec-out getevent /dev/input/event2`). On the other hand, Memu emulator behaves completely opposite. Tested on adb version 1.0.41 (Version 30.0.5-6877874).

(posting this as an answer rather than a comment because of lack of reputation)